# window variable undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with a window level variable.

When I save data in that variable and try to read that data from it, it gives me undefined.

The following is the code:

```
window.cart;

function save(name, sku)
{
    window.cart = "sku: "+sku+", nombre: "+name;
};

function read()
{
    console.log(window.cart);
}
```

Comment: It works fine in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wkrsqar4/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Window.cart is declared and value is not assigned to that and I don't see function save call in your script ,default value of variable in javascript is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your function if you want to access to them and add a onload event to call this when windows body are loaded.

```js
    function save(name, sku)
    {
        window.cart = "sku: "+sku+", nombre: "+name;
    };

    function read()
    {
        console.log(window.cart);
    }

    document.body.onload = function(){
     
      save(20, 'sku_new');
      read();
  
    }
```

Comment: `document.body.onload` is completely unnecessary since the code doesn't access the DOM in any way.